# Bootstrap navbar has bottom margin. Why?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

What is the purpose of having a `margin-bottom: 20px;` on the `.navbar` class? I'm not asking how to get rid of it (that's simple, just do `.navbar {margin-bottom: 0px;}`, but I'm wondering what the design purpose is. It must be useful somewhere, when interacting with other aspects of boostrap. does anyone know?

Comment: To have a 20 pixel gap at the bottom! What else?

Comment: lol... =] +1 for humor

Comment: Haha it was a joke, but also serious. Not sure what other answer could be given.

Comment: It's like the row having a negative 15px margin. The purpose is this http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like leftover code... bloat perhaps?  You're obviously using a "fixed" navbar to have the margin-bottom be 20px.  When you use a STATIC navbar, that margin-bottom is necessary to keep the content below the navbar.

Funny thing is... the static navbar's margin-bottom is set to 19px?

But it looks like it literally does NOTHING with a fixed navbar.

Comment: You sure? Have you tried it on several different browsers? iPad? Tablet? Responsive etc.?

Comment: Pretty sure, I went to Bootstrap's website and compared the static nav to the fixed nav, in one instance, that margin-bottom is necessary.  Have a look... [link](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples)

Comment: There is a border 1px so perhaps the margin is set to 19 to make it 20.

What really makes me curious is that the navbar is height of 50 - 55 px, not 20px.

Comment: I'm not seeing the relevant portion in that link

Comment: It's under "Navbars In Action"... static navbar example and fixed navbar example.